# Can jsp and crystal server pages be cached on the server for speed?

Tags: jsp, crystal-reports

I have several jsp and crystal reports pages on the server that general reports.  Can these be compiled on the server?  I know that asp.net pages are but don't know much about jsp and crystal reports (server).  I just put them both in this question so I didn't create two questions on SO.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to JSP pages: generally speaking, JSP pages are converted into Java servlet code and then compiled into Java bytecode by the application server, in several conditions based on your app server's configuration: 1) when the application is loaded on server startup, 2) when the application is hot-deployed (if your app server supports hot deploys), or 3) when the JSP is changed (if your app is deployed as an exploded EAR/WAR and your server is scanning for file changes).  Otherwise, the JSP is not recompiled and the bytecode version is used to respond to requests.